# Pretty-Print JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, pretty-print, json-simple

I'm using [json-simple](/questions/tagged/json-simple) and I need to pretty-print JSON data (make it more human readable).

I haven't been able to find this functionality within that library.
How is this commonly achieved?

Comment: JsonParser.parseString​(str): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63397831/5626568

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Google's [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) can do this in a nice way:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(uglyJsonString);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

or since it is now recommended to use the static parse method from JsonParser you can also use this instead:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonElement je = JsonParser.parseString​(uglyJsonString);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

Here is the import statement:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
```

Here is the Gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
```

Comment: Well I included code to parse a string into a JsonElement, usually you already have that from previous work you do with the JSON data. But I wanted to include it here to make the usage clearer.

Comment: Since this answer helped me. I have added code below to shrink this statement to fewer lines if this is what you are looking for.

   public String prettifyJson(String json) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
        return new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(jsonElement);
    }

Comment: It is possible to answer the OP's question without needing additional libraries, as you can simply access the JSON parser embedded in Rhino (JDK 1.7 and up). I don't think it is desirable to add a library to a project just to format some debugging output. 
    `scriptEngine.eval("result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString), null, 2)");`

Comment: In contrast to the org.json alternative, the GSON  way of pretty printing keeps the order of the elements intact after transformation.

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845996/6413377) to another related question if interested in more generic solution for example when logging.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `GsonBuilder`, since I was using `gson.toJson(object)` I simply had to change my instantiation from `Gson gson = new Gson();` to `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();`  and my code continued to work but pretty printed the object instead of a single line.

Comment: I urge anyone who only has Jackson as a dependency to see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101386/1087131

Comment: JsonParser is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63397831/5626568

Comment: Why use Google and an additional library if JSON can do this out of the box? This answer should not get marked as solution! This one is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583835/356815

Answer (score 221):

I used [org.json](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) built-in methods to pretty-print the data.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString); // Convert text to object
System.out.println(json.toString(4)); // Print it with specified indentation
```

The order of fields in JSON is random per definition. A specific order is subject to parser implementation.

Comment: I also prefer this solution, because you don't need to import additional dependencies like other answers suggest.

Comment: Missing a crucial import - import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: is there anyway to NOT have the fields in random order, I want it in the order I added them?

Comment: @ThomasAdrian it is not possible with org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: Underscore-java keeps attribute order while formatting json.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I've made a fork of this library (https://github.com/acuna-public/LinkedJSON) which save the elements order, just add `api 'pro.acuna:json:1.0'` string in your build.gradle

Answer (score 77):

With Jackson (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObject))
```

From: [How to enable pretty print JSON output (Jackson)](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-jackson/)

I know this is already in the answers, but I want to write it separately here because chances are, you already have Jackson as a dependency and so all you will need would be an extra line of code

Comment: This will print out an object as a string.  Don't believe it works as-is to pretty print a string of JSON.

Comment: If you have a json in a String you could do:
```ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mapper.readTree(jsonString));```

Answer (score 46):

It seems like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) supports this, although I don't know if you want to switch from the library you are using.

From the user guide:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(someObject);
```

Comment: The problem with GSON, it's complicated, json-simple is far easier.

Comment: I haven't look at this issue in over a year, but if you're willing to modify the source code a bit, http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/issues/detail?id=22 has some information on enhancing json-simple with pretty-printing.

Comment: Got just string without any pretty print formatting :(

Comment: it print String with \r\n

Comment: Thanks. toString() override in one line:   new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(this);

Answer (score 32):

Using org json. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/02/org-json-pretty-print-json.html)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj);
String prettyJson = jsonObject.toString(4);
```

Using Gson. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/11/pretty-print-json-format.html)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Using Jackson. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/10/jackson-pretty-print-json.html)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

Using Genson. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/04/genson-pretty-json.html).

```
Genson prettyGenson = new GensonBuilder().useIndentation(true).create();
String prettyJson = prettyGenson.serialize(obj);
```

Using javax.json. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2021/03/javaxjson-pretty-print-json.html).

```
Map<String, Boolean> config = new HashMap<>();

config.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);

JsonWriterFactory writerFactory = Json.createWriterFactory(config);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();

writerFactory.createWriter(writer).write(jsonObject);

String json = writer.toString();
```

Using Moshi library. Reference [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2021/06/moshi-pretty-print-json.html).

```
String json = jsonAdapter.indent("  ").toJson(emp1);
```

(OR)

```
Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = JsonWriter.of(buffer);
jsonWriter.setIndent("   ");

jsonAdapter.toJson(jsonWriter, emp1);

json = buffer.readUtf8();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. GSON did a horrible job if you need to disable html escaping.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using a Java API for JSON Processing (JSR-353) implementation then you can specify the `JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING` property when you create a `JsonGeneratorFactory`.

The following example has been originally published on my [blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/04/java-api-for-json-processing-jsr-353.html).

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.*;

Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);
JsonGeneratorFactory jgf = Json.createGeneratorFactory(properties);
JsonGenerator jg = jgf.createGenerator(System.out);

jg.writeStartObject()                    // {
    .write("name", "Jane Doe")           //    "name":"Jane Doe",
    .writeStartObject("address")         //    "address":{
        .write("type", 1)                //        "type":1,
        .write("street", "1 A Street")   //        "street":"1 A Street",
        .writeNull("city")               //        "city":null,
        .write("verified", false)        //        "verified":false
    .writeEnd()                          //    },
    .writeStartArray("phone-numbers")    //    "phone-numbers":[
        .writeStartObject()              //        {
            .write("number", "555-1111") //            "number":"555-1111",
            .write("extension", "123")   //            "extension":"123"
        .writeEnd()                      //        },
        .writeStartObject()              //        {
            .write("number", "555-2222") //            "number":"555-2222",
            .writeNull("extension")      //            "extension":null
        .writeEnd()                      //        }
    .writeEnd()                          //    ]
.writeEnd()                              // }
.close();
```

Answer (score 21):

Pretty printing with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) in one line:

```
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(new JsonParser().parse(jsonString)));
```

Besides inlining, this is equivalent to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310424/906658).

Answer (score 19):

My situation is my project uses a legacy (non-JSR) JSON parser that does not support pretty printing. However, I needed to produce pretty-printed JSON samples; this is possible without having to add any extra libraries as long as you are using Java 7 and above:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
scriptEngine.put("jsonString", jsonStringNoWhitespace);
scriptEngine.eval("result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString), null, 2)");
String prettyPrintedJson = (String) scriptEngine.get("result");
```

Comment: This is awsome, use the js engine to do it, so much simpler

Comment: warning if you care: the ScriptEngineManager is not API.

Answer (score 18):

Most of the existing answers either depend on some external library, or requiring a special Java version. Here is a simple code to pretty print a JSON string, only using general Java APIs (available in Java 7 for higher; haven't tried older version although).

The basic idea is to tigger the formatting based on special characters in JSON. For example, if a '{' or '[' is observed, the code will create a new line and increase the indent level.

Disclaimer: I only tested this for some simple JSON cases (basic key-value pair, list, nested JSON) so it may need some work for more general JSON text, like string value with quotes inside, or special characters (\n, \t etc.).

```
/**
 * A simple implementation to pretty-print JSON file.
 *
 * @param unformattedJsonString
 * @return
 */
public static String prettyPrintJSON(String unformattedJsonString) {
  StringBuilder prettyJSONBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  int indentLevel = 0;
  boolean inQuote = false;
  for(char charFromUnformattedJson : unformattedJsonString.toCharArray()) {
    switch(charFromUnformattedJson) {
      case '"':
        // switch the quoting status
        inQuote = !inQuote;
        prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
        break;
      case ' ':
        // For space: ignore the space if it is not being quoted.
        if(inQuote) {
          prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
        }
        break;
      case '{':
      case '[':
        // Starting a new block: increase the indent level
        prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
        indentLevel++;
        appendIndentedNewLine(indentLevel, prettyJSONBuilder);
        break;
      case '}':
      case ']':
        // Ending a new block; decrese the indent level
        indentLevel--;
        appendIndentedNewLine(indentLevel, prettyJSONBuilder);
        prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
        break;
      case ',':
        // Ending a json item; create a new line after
        prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
        if(!inQuote) {
          appendIndentedNewLine(indentLevel, prettyJSONBuilder);
        }
        break;
      default:
        prettyJSONBuilder.append(charFromUnformattedJson);
    }
  }
  return prettyJSONBuilder.toString();
}

/**
 * Print a new line with indention at the beginning of the new line.
 * @param indentLevel
 * @param stringBuilder
 */
private static void appendIndentedNewLine(int indentLevel, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
  stringBuilder.append("\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < indentLevel; i++) {
    // Assuming indention using 2 spaces
    stringBuilder.append("  ");
  }
}
```

Comment: On first reading I was highly displeasured with this suggestion, but after reading all answers, this is the best solution. At least, if it is for just for some debugging output, and you don't want to drag in dependencies, that you might want to remove later on again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

Now this can be achieved with the JSONLib library:

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html

If (and only if) you use the overloaded `toString(int indentationFactor)` method and not the standard `toString()` method.

I have verified this on the following version of the API:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this library may help answer the question, it would be better to include an _example_ of how it is applicable to the problem with some _explanation_ regarding how it works.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. Though do remember, people like me are volunteers and are not getting paid to provide a service that guarantees meeting quality standards. We have limited time because we're often in the middle of work, or have family duties. That's why "edit" is available to readers, so we can make each others' posts more helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Following the JSON-P 1.0 specs ([JSR-353](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353)) a more current solution for a given `JsonStructure` (`JsonObject` or `JsonArray`) could look like this:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonStructure;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;
import javax.json.JsonWriterFactory;
import javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator;

public class PrettyJson {

    private static JsonWriterFactory FACTORY_INSTANCE;

    public static String toString(final JsonStructure status) {

        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = getPrettyJsonWriterFactory()
                .createWriter(stringWriter);

        jsonWriter.write(status);
        jsonWriter.close();

        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    private static JsonWriterFactory getPrettyJsonWriterFactory() {
        if (null == FACTORY_INSTANCE) {
            final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(1);
            properties.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);
            FACTORY_INSTANCE = Json.createWriterFactory(properties);
        }
        return FACTORY_INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

In JSONLib you can use this:

```
String jsonTxt = JSONUtils.valueToString(json, 8, 4);
```

From the [Javadoc](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/util/JSONUtils.html#valueToString(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use Gson like below

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(object);
```

From the post [JSON pretty print using Gson](http://javabycode.com/java-core/json-tutorial/json-pretty-print-using-gson.html)

Alternatively, You can use Jackson like below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String perttyStr = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
```

From the post [Pretty print JSON in Java (Jackson)](http://javabycode.com/java-core/json-tutorial/pretty-print-json-in-java-jackson.html)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:  `new JsonParser().parse(...)` is `@deprecated`

---

Based on the javadoc for **Gson 2.8.6**:

> No need to instantiate this class, use the static methods instead.

**JsonParser** static methods:

```
JsonParser.parseString​(jsonString);
JsonParser.parseReader​(reader);
```

---

Packages:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

Example:

```
private Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
public static String getPerfectJSON(String unformattedJSON) {
    String perfectJSON = GSON.toJson(JsonParser.parseString(unformattedJSON));
    return perfectJSON;
}
```

---

**Google Gson** dependency using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

---

#### Reference:

- [JsonParser is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771386/jsonparser-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, using Jackson:

```
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(JSONString)
```

Comment: Where this `mapper` came from?

Answer (score 1):

So I too like the `json-simple` lib, and looked into pretty printing its output. Unfortunately, while it's an [open issue there](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/issues/136), I couldn't find any code for it. So I thought I'd give it a try, here's what I came up with (using their own source)..

```
public class JsonPrinter {
  
  
  
  public static String toJson(Map<?,?> map) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(32);
    new JsonPrinter(out).print(map);
    return out.toString();
  }
  
  
  public static String toJson(List<?> list) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(32);
    new JsonPrinter(out).print(list);
    return out.toString();
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  private final Appendable out;
  private final String indentUnit;
  private final String newLine;
  
  
  private int indents;
  
  public JsonPrinter(Appendable out) {
    this(out, "  ", System.lineSeparator());
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  public JsonPrinter(Appendable out, String indentUnit, String newLine) {
    this.out = Objects.requireNonNull(out, "null out");
    this.indentUnit = Objects.requireNonNull(indentUnit, "null indentUnit");
    this.newLine = Objects.requireNonNull(newLine, "null newLine");
    
    if (!indentUnit.isBlank())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "indentUnit must be a blank sequence (quoted): '" + indentUnit + "'");
    if (!"\r\n".equals(newLine) && ! "\n".equals(newLine))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "unrecognized newLine (quoted): '" + newLine + "'");
  }
  
  
  public void print(List<?> list) throws UncheckedIOException {
    try {
      assert indents == 0;
      printImpl(list);
      assert indents == 0;
    } catch (IOException iox) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException("on print(List): " + list, iox);
    }
  }
  
  
  public void print(Map<?,?> map) throws UncheckedIOException {
    try {
      assert indents == 0;
      printImpl(map);
      assert indents == 0;
    } catch (IOException iox) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException("on print(Map): " + map, iox);
    }
  }
  
  
  protected void printImpl(List<?> list) throws IOException {
    if (list == null) {
      out.append("null");
      return;
    }
    
    
    boolean first = true;
    var iter = list.iterator();
    
    open('[');
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      if (first)
        first = false;
      else
        out.append(',');
      
      out.append(newLine);
      appendIndents();
      
      appendValue(iter.next());
    }
    close(']');
  }
  
  
  protected void printImpl(Map<?, ?> map) throws IOException {
    if (map == null) {
      out.append("null");
      return;
    }
    
    
    boolean first = true;
    var iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    
    open('{');
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      if (first)
        first = false;
      else
        out.append(',');
      
      out.append(newLine);
      appendIndents();
      
      var entry = iter.next();
      print(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());
    }
    close('}');
  }
  
  
  private void open(char c) throws IOException {
    out.append(c);
    ++indents;
  }
  
  private void close(char c) throws IOException {
    --indents;
    out.append(newLine);
    appendIndents();
    out.append(c);
  }
  
  private void appendIndents() throws IOException {
    for (int count = indents; count-- > 0; )
      out.append(indentUnit);
  }
  
  
  
  private void print(String key, Object value) throws IOException {
    out.append('"');
    appendString(key);
    out.append('"').append(':').append(' ');
    appendValue(value);
  }
  
  
  
  private void appendString(String s) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      char ch = s.charAt(i);
      switch(ch){
      case '"':
        out.append("\\\"");
        break;
      case '\\':
        out.append("\\\\");
        break;
      case '\b':
        out.append("\\b");
        break;
      case '\f':
        out.append("\\f");
        break;
      case '\n':
        out.append("\\n");
        break;
      case '\r':
        out.append("\\r");
        break;
      case '\t':
        out.append("\\t");
        break;
      case '/':
        out.append("\\/");
        break;
      default:
                //Reference: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/
        if ((ch>='\u0000' && ch<='\u001F') || (ch>='\u007F' && ch<='\u009F') || (ch>='\u2000' && ch<='\u20FF')) {
          String ss = Integer.toHexString(ch);
          out.append("\\u");
          for (int k=0; k < 4-ss.length(); k++) {
            out.append('0');
          }
          out.append(ss.toUpperCase());
        }
        else{
          out.append(ch);
        }
      }
    }//for
  }
  
  
  private void appendValue(Object value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      out.append("null");
      
    } else if (value instanceof String) {
      out.append('"');
      appendString(value.toString());
      out.append('"');
      
    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
      var num = (Double) value;
      if (num.isInfinite() || num.isNaN())
        out.append("null");
      else
        out.append(value.toString());
      
    } else if (value instanceof Float) {
      var num = (Float) value;
      if (num.isInfinite() || num.isNaN())
        out.append("null");
      else
        out.append(value.toString());
      
    } else if (value instanceof Map) {
      printImpl((Map<?,?>) value);
      
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
      printImpl((List<?>) value);
      
//    } else if (value instanceof Number || value instanceof Boolean) {
//      out.append(value.toString());
      
    } else {
      out.append(value.toString());
      
    }
  }

}
```

It works for `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` even tho it has no dependeny on them.. cuz these are regular `Map` and `List` objects resp. (*and the fact code was lifted from same lib*).

https://github.com/crums-io/io-util/blob/master/src/main/java/io/crums/util/json/JsonPrinter.java

Answer (score 1):

This would be a public method to print a pretty version of your object (You need the Gson dependency installed:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
...

public void printMe(){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String prettyJSON = gson.toJson(this);
    System.out.println(printable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use small [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library

```
String jsonstring = ....;
JsonValue json = JsonParser.parse(jsonstring);
String jsonIndendedByTwoSpaces = json.toPrettyString("  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use the org.json.simple package. I have simply coded the formatter, but since I don't have nulls, numbers or booleans in my JSON objects in the program that I wrote, I only coded for strings, objects and arrays. If anyone is interested, let this just be in the public domain. You are welcome to add the missing data types (where it says in the comment "it's a string"). Also, you can add the indentation as a parameter whereas mine is just two spaces. Please reshare after you've tested your improvements.

**Usage**: `printJsonObject(jsonObject, "");`

**Functions**:

```
    public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject object, String prefix) {
        boolean notFirst = false;
        System.out.println(prefix + "{");
        for (Object key : object.keySet()) {
            if (notFirst) {
                System.out.println(", ");
            }
            notFirst = true;
            Object value = object.get(key);
            System.out.print(prefix + "  " + "\"" + key + "\"" + ": ");
            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                printJsonObject((JSONObject) value, prefix + "  ");
            } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                printJsonArray((JSONArray) value, prefix + "  ");
            } else {  // it's a string
                System.out.print("\"" + value + "\"");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(prefix + "}");
    }

    public static void printJsonArray(JSONArray array, String prefix) {
        boolean notFirst = false;
        System.out.println("[");
        for (Object item : array) {
            if (notFirst) {
                System.out.println(", ");
            }
            notFirst = true;
            if (item instanceof JSONObject) {
                printJsonObject((JSONObject) item, prefix + "  ");
            } else if (item instanceof JSONArray) {
                printJsonArray((JSONArray) item, prefix + "  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(prefix + "  " + "\"" + item + "\"");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(prefix + "]");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) has static method `U.formatJson(json)`.
Five format types are supported: 2, 3, 4, tabs and compact. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/XrW)

```java
import com.github.underscore.U;

import static com.github.underscore.Json.JsonStringBuilder.Step.TABS;
import static com.github.underscore.Json.JsonStringBuilder.Step.TWO_SPACES;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String json = "{\"Price\": {"
        + "    \"LineItems\": {"
        + "        \"LineItem\": {"
        + "            \"UnitOfMeasure\": \"EACH\", \"Quantity\": 2, \"ItemID\": \"ItemID\""
        + "        }"
        + "    },"
        + "    \"Currency\": \"USD\","
        + "    \"EnterpriseCode\": \"EnterpriseCode\""
        + "}}";
        System.out.println(U.formatJson(json, TWO_SPACES)); 
        System.out.println(U.formatJson(json, TABS)); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Price": {
    "LineItems": {
      "LineItem": {
        "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH",
        "Quantity": 2,
        "ItemID": "ItemID"
      }
    },
    "Currency": "USD",
    "EnterpriseCode": "EnterpriseCode"
  }
}
{
    "Price": {
        "LineItems": {
            "LineItem": {
                "UnitOfMeasure": "EACH",
                "Quantity": 2,
                "ItemID": "ItemID"
            }
        },
        "Currency": "USD",
        "EnterpriseCode": "EnterpriseCode"
    }
}
```