# How do I pretty-print existing JSON data with Java?

Tags: java, json, formatting, pretty-print

I have a compact JSON string, and I want to format it nicely in Java without having to deserialize it first -- e.g. just like [jsonlint.org](http://jsonlint.org) does it.  Are there any libraries out there that provides this?

A similar solution for XML would also be nice.

Comment: By pretty print, do you mean color-code, indent, or both?

Comment: JSONObject has a `toString(int)` where you provide spacing for pretty printing.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I would need to deserialize the JSON data to get a JSONObject, wouldn't I?

Comment: @neu242, no, JSONObject is a JSON data already. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: GWT 2.5.0 doesn't have a toString(int) on JSONObject

Comment: I would look at Nashorn (part of a java installation). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java#29094958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for pretty-printing something, it's very helpful to know its structure.

To get the structure you have to [parse](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) it.  Because of this, I don't think it gets much easier than first parsing the JSON string you have and then using the pretty-printing method [toString](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29) mentioned in the comments above.

Of course you can do similar with any JSON library you like.

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 97):

```
int spacesToIndentEachLevel = 2;
new JSONObject(jsonString).toString(spacesToIndentEachLevel);
```

Using `org.json.JSONObject` (built in to JavaEE and Android)

Comment: What library does this use? As is it is not a very helpful answer.

Comment: @Andrew Backer, this is not a library. As Heath Borders said, it is built into the Android libraries. I've tested this and it works perfectly without any libraries.

Comment: Hm... I'm not developing for Android, and I don't deploy to a java EE container... hence the need for clarification.  Thanks for adding that :)  So for someone like me, distributing a java app targeting SE, it would be a library such as `org.json:json:20090211`?

Comment: for those of us using Android, this is very useful and not really clear in the quick view of the docs. Didn't expect it to be built in.

Comment: **`org.json.JSONObject` is not built into JavaEE**. The `JSON-P` library for `JsonObject` is `javax.json.JsonObject`.

Comment: greattttt, this is very useful

Comment: The dependency with group ID of `org.json` and artifact ID of `json` in the Maven POM file or in your Gradle also supports prettifying JSON data by passing in the indent level in the `toString(int)` method.

Comment: This is really useful in Spring Boot.

Comment: this is very useful. but one problem. if data is large, all data not showing in. Any suggestion

Answer (score 24):

Use gson. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(my_bean);
```

output

```
{
  "name": "mkyong",
  "age": 35,
  "position": "Founder",
  "salary": 10000,
  "skills": [
    "java",
    "python",
    "shell"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another way to use gson:

```
String json_String_to_print = ...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
return gson.toJson(jp.parse(json_String_to_print));
```

It can be used when you don't have the bean as in susemi99's post.

Comment: Instantiating `JsonParser` is now deprecated. Use the static method `JsonParser.parseString(json_String_to_print)` instead.

Comment: This is the right answer let's up vote it !!

Comment: this must be accepted answer!

Answer (score 11):

If you are using jackson you can easily achieve this with configuring a `SerializationFeature` in your `ObjectMapper`:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

mapper.writeValueAsString(<yourObject>);
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

I fount a very simple solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code:

```
import com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonWriter;
//...
String jsonString = "json_string_plain_text";
System.out.println(JsonWriter.formatJson(jsonString));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has methods `U.formatJson(json)` and `U.formatXml(xml)`.