# Json Object Array Write in Java line by line

Tags: java, arrays, json, printing

I have a Array  with some value 
when i store that array i got result like this

```
[{"id":56678,"Name":"Rehman Agarwal"},{"id":66849,"Name":"Rasul Guha"}]
```

means in a single line.

but I just want to get output like

```
[{"id":56678,"Name":"Rehman Agarwal"},
{"id":66849,"Name":"Rasul Guha"}]
```

new line after JSON object ..

How to do it ?

EDIT : *i use* `JSONObject && JSONArray` *for create json Object and array respectively*

Comment: Do any of the answers help from this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185337/how-do-i-pretty-print-existing-json-data-with-java

Comment: Quick and dirty, replace `"\"},{\""` by `"\"},\n{\""`.

Comment: `replace("},{", "},\n{")` solve the prob .. Thanks @maraca for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using gson library you can pretty print your json strings like below -

```
public static String toPrettyFormat(String jsonString) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String prettyJson = gson.toJson(json);

    return prettyJson;
}
```

And call it like below -

```
public void testPrettyPrint() {
    String compactJson = "{\"playerID\":1234,\"name\":\"Test\",\"itemList\":[{\"itemID\":1,\"name\":\"Axe\",\"atk\":12,\"def\":0},{\"itemID\":2,\"name\":\"Sword\",\"atk\":5,\"def\":5},{\"itemID\":3,\"name\":\"Shield\",\"atk\":0,\"def\":10}]}";

    String prettyJson = toPrettyFormat(compactJson);

    System.out.println("Compact:\n" + compactJson);
    System.out.println("Pretty:\n" + prettyJson);
}
```

Comment: Are there any builtin ways of doing this?  Adding a library just to print each entry on a  new lines seems over the board.