# Pretty JSON format with GAE Java

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pretty-Print JSON in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

I am using Java JSON library provided by google for google app engine. My JSON output somewhat looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"name":"John"},{"age":10}],"status":"success"}
```

Not human-readable and hard to debug. How can I turn the output into something like this?

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"John"
      },
      {
         "age":10
      }
   ],
   "status":"success"
}
```

Or some other form instead of "one-line output".

Comment: You can always use the JSONView plugin on Google Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc which prettifies the output.

Comment: - the thread that u mentioned using simple json to solve the problem. I am using gae provided lib which not able to solve this
- i want to do it in the way that there is no need for end user to use plugin to view json output

Comment: @SilverTsuki Most of the libraries mentioned in the link above by Trevor (e.g. Jackson, GSON) will work on GAE