# Getting correct output from json object in java

Tags: java, android, json

**my code is:**

```
 JSONObject jChild=new JSONObject();
         JSONObject jParent=new JSONObject();
            for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
              if (p.checked){
                try {
                    jChild.put("uid", p.uid);
                list.add(String.valueOf(jChild));

                    //list.add(String.valueOf(jParent));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
            jParent.put("users", list);

          // Toast.makeText(this, ""+jParent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v("TakeAttendance","JSONpARENT "+String.valueOf(jParent));
```

**Output :**

```
{"users":"[{\"uid\":\"4\"}, {\"uid\":\"5\"}, {\"uid\":\"6\"}]"}
```

**What i actually need :**

```
  {users: [
    {
    name: "acx",
    uid: "2"
    },

    {
    name: "test",
    uid: "6"
    },

    {
    name: "ccc",
    uid: "11"
    }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: You're nowhere putting the `name` attribute so obviously your output does not have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If list is `JSONArray` ..

```
         JSONObject jParent=new JSONObject();
         JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
         try {
            for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {                  
              if (p.checked){
                JSONObject jChild=new JSONObject(); //Correction here   
                    jChild.put("uid", p.uid);
                list.add(jChild);        //Correction here                       

              }
            }
            jParent.put("users", list);    
           } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Log.v("TakeAttendance","JSONpARENT "+jParent); //Correction here
```

Comment: JSON requires both key and value are strings. If you need pretty print JSON object, try [pretty-print-json-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

JSON requires both key and value are strings. If you need pretty print JSON object, try [pretty-print-json-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Correct JOSNObject will be

```
     {"users": [

    {
    "name": "acx",
    "uid": "2"
    },

    {
    "name": "test",
    "uid": "6"
    },

    {
    "name": "ccc",
    "uid": "11"
    }
  ]

}

String data ; // JOSN String
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray array = data.getJSONArray("users");
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = obj.getString("name");
        String uid  = obj.getString("uid");
}
```

For generating from Data

```
            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(); 
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray ();
            for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
              if (p.checked){
                try {
                     JSONObject jChild=new JSONObject();
                     jChild.put("uid", p.uid);
                     jChild.put("name", p.name);
                     list.add(String.valueOf(jChild));

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              }
            }
            jParent.put("users", list);
```

Comment: Actually it is formatting and getting correct output as shown above.Log.v() should print the data that i need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is actually correct JSON. It will be parsed back to a JSON object correctly. If you want this only for printing purpose, you can just replace '\"' with blank string.