# JSON: Display JSON String on HTML website

Tags: html, json

I would like my webpage to display what resembles [JASON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)
does (right panel). I first installed JSONView on my Chrome.

Then I composed a string **{"isbn":"asdf","name":"qwer","price":1}** which I fed to JSON Parser and made sure it indeed obeyed JSON format.

Eventually, I attempted to display it on my webpage by doing:

```
out.println("{\"isbn\":\"asdf\",\"name\":\"qwer\",\"price\":1}\");
```

but it was simply displayed like any other normal String instead of being formatted like this. [image]
How do I manage to make my webpage automatically display JSON formatted?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I didn't realise this was JSP. The answer I'm giving relates to using the JavaScript method `JSON.stringify()` which you'd somehow achieve within client-side JavaScript within your JSP project.

---

Use `JSON.stringify()` to 'pretty-print' the original JavaScript object.

For example, to have two spaces of indentation:

`var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);`

---

If this has to be achieved within Java code then you could use the GSON library. Example: [Pretty-Print JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

Comment: Thank you to begin with....
I try not to turn this into a step-by-step tutorial for noob like me, but I am writing JSP and my Intellij told me "var" and "JSON" could not be resolved. Am I missing JSON library?

Comment: Oh, sorry. `JSON.stringify()` is a JavaScript method available natively on most browsers (I think). I didn't notice the `out.println` and didn't realise this was JSP. I know nothing about JSP I'm afraid (other than that it's based on Java). If this task must be done in Java (or by whatever the end result actually is - I don't know if JSP 'compiles' out to JavaScript or whatever) then try using GSON (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java). Or alternatively can you embed a snippet of JavaScript to do the `JSON.stringify()`?