# how to print complete json http request results in java

Tags: java, json, httprequest

Unable to print complete JSON Results. My Program as follows:

Am new to this program. Unable to find the reason for the error.

Query for the program as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H 
"Content-Type:application/json" --header 
'X-Auth-Token:IEkmVGHsa4R3cGPw56MkfQ' -d '{
"sensor_key":"e4aa3e35t675fc57ce81f3dd6e2dcdef492at4f7", 
"date_ranges":[{
"from":"2015/04/02 17:05:00", 
"to":"2015/04/02 17:10:00"
}], 
"time_zone":"Mumbai" , 
"time_format":"str", 
"per":"50"
}' 
'https://api.datonis.io/api/v2/datonis_query/sensor_event_raw_data


    package IOT;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.json.JSONArray;

    public class HttpPostWithBody {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Message = "6f2159f998";

    try {
        new HttpPostWithBody().sendJSONData(Message);
    } catch (Exception E) {
    System.out.println("Exception Occured. " + E.getMessage());
    }
    }

    public String sendJSONData(String message) throws Exception {

    //creating map object to create JSON object from it
    Map< String, Object >jsonValues = new HashMap< String, Object >();
    jsonValues.put("sensor_key",message);
    jsonValues.put("from", "2016/08/29 16:55:00");
    jsonValues.put("to", "2016/08/29 17:05:00");
    jsonValues.put("time_zone", "Mumbai");
    jsonValues.put("per", "50");
    jsonValues.put("metrics", "1st data");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);


    String url = "https://api.datonis.io/api/v2/datonis_query/sensor_event_raw_data";

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
    post.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", "9v8IjBku0a9y-D7SpLq6ZA");

    //setting json object to post request.
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

    post.setEntity(entity);
    //this is your response:

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    //JSONObject myObject1 = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);

    //JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject();
    System.out.println("Response: " + ja.getJSONObject(0));

    System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
    return response.getStatusLine().toString();
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is not helpfull to other users to post questions without a full problem description. What is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: Your Answer is really helpful. Am new to this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(json.toString());
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
System.out.println(prettyJsonString);
```

Output:

```
{
  "sensor_key": "6f2159f998",
  "from": "2016/08/29 16:55:00",
  "to": "2016/08/29 17:05:00",
  "metrics": "1st data",
  "time_zone": "Mumbai",
  "per": "50"
}
```

[image]

See the whole code, **[here](http://collabedit.com/q4n8x)**

For more info about GSON library, check **[this](https://github.com/google/gson)**

To download GSON, check **[this](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=gson&g=com.google.code.gson&v=2.7&downloadable=1)**

Comment: I couldn't understand this. Can you please help me in write / change my program ans post the same.

Comment: @GaneshRavikumar Stack Overflow is not a coding writing service.

Comment: @GaneshRavikumar: I already put a link that takes you to the whole code in my answer, [check it](http://collabedit.com/q4n8x)

Comment: am getting the results which post the actual result will be as follows: Returns upto 50 events.
{
  "e4aa3e35t675fc57ce81f3dd6e2dcdef492at4f7": {
    "total_event_count": 30,
    "page_number": 1,
    "event_data": [
      {
        "data": {
          "mem": 208,
          "cpu": 1.3250000000000002
        },
        "time_stamp": "2015/04/02 17:09:59"
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "mem": 219,
          "cpu": 1.45

Comment: Can you help me on this pls the another error as follows: Exception Occured. JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.

The recent AUTHENDICATION KEY IS: SOX_0P37BCqoigWZ-gcC5w

Comment: @GaneshRavikumar: I think that you should ask another question related to this error and I or other people will help you, and it seems that this answer is enough to your question and you should close the question by accepting the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probabbly, you should use the same solution:
[Pretty-Print JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

Also, [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) is quite good overall