# JsonObject getAsString throwing Exception

Tags: java, json

I am new to java, and I am trying to create a json string with `name` and `value`.

```
public static String serializeToken(String name,String value){

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty(name, value);

    return json.getAsString();
}
```

But the call to `getAsString` throws an exception and message is just:

> JsonObject

Comment: Can't you just use json.toString()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java

Comment: toString escapes the `"` with `\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsString--) the documentation of `getAsString` method and this is what it says:

> convenience method to get this element as a string value.
>
> Throws:
>
> ClassCastException - if the element is of not a JsonPrimitive
>   and is not a valid string value. IllegalStateException - if the
>   element is of the type JsonArray but contains more than a single
>   element.

So, if the element is not a Primitive (which it is not, in this case), it will throw an `Exception`. If you want to print `json` String then you need to call `toString` method, e.g.:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("test", "value");
String jsonString = json.toString(); 
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Comment: it worked. one more thing please.. when you say element is not primitive. what do you mean by `element`?

Comment: element = object which the method is being called on. `json` in our case..