# How convert a POJO into a readable string on Android for debugging?

Tags: android, json, gson

Given a the following plain-text JSON object

```
class Chat {

    String id;
    String title;
    List<String> messages;

}
```

how to I override `toString` in order to it be **human readable only for debugging**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize it into a JSON string:

```
class Chat {

    private static final GSON = new GSON();

    String id;
    String title;
    List<String> messages;

    public String toString() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG ? GSON.toJson(this) : super.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your own solution works but it is not too generic. I would create a helper class (if not want to do inline on every print)

```
public class PrettyPrinter {

   private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .setPrettyPrinting().create();

   public static String print(Object o) {
      return gson.toJson(o);
   }

}
```

so you can

```
PrettyPrinter.print(chat);
```

If you insist to use `toString()` it would then be

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return isDebugEnabled() ? PrettyPrinter.print(this) : super.toString();
   // or BuildConfig.DEBUG ? ...;
}
```

or maybe you want to make it by extending a class like this

```
public class JsonPrintable {

   public String toString() {
      return isDebugEnabled() ? PrettyPrinter.print(this) : super.toString();
   }
   /**
    * this should be logging dependent implementation
    * @return
    */
   public boolean isDebugEnabled() {
      return log.isDebugEnabled(); // personally use slf4j for logging... 
      // or return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
   } 
}
```

so

```
public class Chat extends JsonPrintable { ... }
```

Comment: Updated answer with missing debug check

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to Chat

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nIngrediente{" +
            "\n\tid='" + id + '\'' +
            "\n\ttitle='" + title + '\'' +
            "\n\tmessages=" + messages +
            "\n}";
}
```

note that `ArrayList` are already printable, at this point you can easily

```
Chat chat = new Chat();
Log.d("Printing!", chat);
```

Works for me.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I used this toString a while ago, i found it on stackoverflow and edited it a little but i don't remember the source link:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    result.append( this.getClass().getName() );
    result.append( " Object {" );
    result.append(newLine);

    //determine fields declared in this class only (no fields of superclass)
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    //print field names paired with their values
    for ( Field field : fields  ) {
        result.append("  ");
        try {
            if (field.isSynthetic() || field.getName().equals("serialVersionUID"))
                continue;
            result.append( field.getName() );
            result.append(": ");
            //requires access to private field:
            result.append( field.get(this) );
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        result.append(newLine);
    }
    result.append("}");

    return result.toString();
}
```

tweaking it a little you can actually print all the property in any pojo without having to add them every time to *toString*

Comment: Using this approach, every time I add/remove an attribute to `Chat` class, `toString` will have to be modified. Furthermore there is no need of indenting the `String` because we may _beautify_ it using the programming editor.

Comment: Updated, i added a way to print all fields automatically.