# Output a JSON string with previous Format in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON flat file and I need to change the value of clientCode

```
{
  "clientNumber": "Test",
  "clientCode": "12345",
  "clientReference": "JSON Testing",
  "billingCode":"90code",
  "clienttructure": "new, test, Java",
  "site": "sampleStore",
  "siteDestination": "EU",
}
```

I tried to change clientCode value and check the return of the method.

I'm Using Java

```
String jsonName = "clientCode ";
String jsonValue = "new Value";
String JSONSource = path;


public String put(String jsonName, String jsonValue, String JSONSource) {
        String jsonString = null;

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(JSONSource));
            org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;

            jsonObject.put(jsonName, jsonValue);

            jsonString = jsonObject.toJSONString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
```

Actual output is:

```
{ "billingCode":"90code", "clientCode": "new Value","clientNumber": "Test","clientReference": "JSON Testing",.....}
```

Expected output should be :

```
{
  "clientNumber": "Test",
  "clientCode": "new Value",
  "clientReference": "JSON Testing",
  "billingCode":"90code",
  "clienttructure": "new, test, Java",
  "site": "sampleStore",
  "siteDestination": "EU",
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need the output in a specific order?

Comment: You did not mention the API you are using.

Comment: Complementing @brandonx comment, following the [RFC 7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), *an object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more value/pairs *, so I don't know if your requirement really makes sense

Comment: If you really need to keep the order and formatting, a string replacement using a regular expression may also be an option (although not really a recommended way to process JSON).

Comment: @all just want to make the formatting output so that other developer in our team can easily read the json file, also it will be used for our logging.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java

Answer (score 0):

### Try this...

```
JSONObject jsonobject =  new JSONObject(response);
jsonobject .remove("clientCode");

JSONObject updateValue = new JSONObject(updateValue);
String UpdatedValue = updateValue.getString("clientCode");
jsonobject .put("clientCode", UpdatedValue);
```