# JsonParser is deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, parsing, gson, jsonparser

Getting deprecated message for `JsonParser` for Spring Boot app,

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject();
```

**What is the alternative?**

Comment: If the JsonPraser used is [this](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#%3Cinit%3E()) , then the message says _No need to instantiate this class, use the static methods instead._

Comment: Also you may use correct static method based on the `parse()` param

Comment: I am using `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6`

Comment: No `parse()` method available for JsonParser class

Comment: The code shared shows `parse(result)` method used, there are alternative static methods for the `result` type. What is the type of the `result` parameter ? String , Reader or JsonReader ?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Based on the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) for Gson 2.8.6

> No need to instantiate this class, use the static methods instead.

and following are the alternatives to be used.

```java
// jsonString is of type java.lang.String
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString​(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

// reader is of type java.io.Reader
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseReader​(reader).getAsJsonObject();

// jsonReader is of type com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseReader​(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();
```

Example

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{ \"name\":\"John\"}";

        JsonObject jsonObjectAlt = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        // Shows deprecated warning for new JsonParser() and parse(jsonString)
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();

        assertTrue(jsonObjectAlt.equals(jsonObject));

    }
}
```

Comment: Getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject` afte I used `JsonObject jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString​(result).getAsJsonObject();`

Comment: What is the `result` type ? It should be a String object

Comment: type is of `JsonObject`

Comment: `JsonParser.parseString​(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();` the parameter here should be a `String` object. For you the parameter name is `result` , convert that to `String` and attempt. (probably a `.toString()`)

Comment: Checking. This is documented alternative for the code shared with question

Comment: Code works without any issues . Could you please share a sample string that fails ?

Comment: @R.G do you know if this is threadsafe?  I have multiple parses happening in parallel...

Answer (score 0):

new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(new JSONParser(jsonString).parse());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).