# Convert Buffered Reader in JSONObject (json-simple)

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple, rest

i'm calling a Rest API in GET, and i need to parse the response and take the value of a key.
I'm using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my code:

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(readLine);
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            jsonObject.get();
            in.close();
```

But in `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());` generate a error
Error:(32, 63) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Map

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `JSONParser` to get the data from String:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
```

`JSONObject` is used to serialize its data into JSON string via `toJSONString()` method.

Comment: Thanks so much. If now i want take the value, how do, i tried json.get('key1') but nothing, the structure is like this {status:200 data:{key1:value,key2:value}}, i want get key1:value. Thanks so much

Comment: You need to get `data` object first, and then get `key1` out of it:

`String v1 = ((JSONObject)simpleJson.get("data")).get("key1").toString();`

Comment: I did in this way and work ...  `JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
            JSONObject jsonData = (JSONObject) json.get("data");
            String stringTranslated = (String) jsonData.get("translation");`

Comment: `JSONParser` is deprecated.

Comment: It's Gson's `JsonParser` that is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771386/).  Initial question was tagged and related to another Json Library [`json-simple`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) which has been godforsaken for a long time.  [v.1.1.1 JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/latest/index.html) does not mention deprecation.

Comment: However, it appears this project was forked and continued at Clifton Labs, [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.cliftonlabs/json-simple), where [JSONParser](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.github.cliftonlabs/json-simple/2.3.0/source-code/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java) got deprecated -- but this is definitely another story.