# Converting json in a file to standard format using java

Tags: java, json

I am using json simple to handle json array in java. This is the code below:

```
            JSONObject job=new JSONObject();
            try{job.put("roll-no",Integer.parseInt(rollnoprompt.getText()));}
            catch(Exception e){}
            JSONArray Marks=new JSONArray();


            for(int i=0;i<mrkcls.size();++i){

            JSONObject job1=new JSONObject();
            job1.put("Question-no",i+1);
            job1.put("total-marks",Float.parseFloat(mrkcls.get(i).questionMarks.getText()));

            JSONArray Parts=new JSONArray();
            char ch=97;
            java.util.List<JTextField> partsMarksList=mrkcls.get(i).partsMarks;

            for(int j=0;j<partsMarksList.size();++j){
                JSONObject job2=new JSONObject();
                job2.put("part",Character.toString(ch));
                job2.put("marks",Float.parseFloat(partsMarksList.get(j).getText()));

                ++ch;
                Parts.add(job2);
            }

            job1.put("Parts",Parts);
            Marks.add(job1);
        }   
        job.put("Marks",Marks);
        reportCard.add(job);
        //System.out.println(job);

        FileWriter file=new FileWriter("Result.json");
        file.write(reportCard.toJSONString());

        file.flush();
        file.close();
```

I notice that the json array in file Result.json is written in a straight line, something like this:

```
[{"roll-no":1,"Marks":[{"Parts":[{"part":"a","marks":2.0},{"part":"b","marks":1.0},{"part":"c","marks":2.0}],"Question-no":1,"total-marks":5.0},{"Parts":[{"part":"a","marks":2.0},{"part":"b","marks":2.0}],"Question-no":2,"total-marks":4.0},{"Parts":[],"Question-no":3,"total-marks":4.0},{"Parts":[{"part":"a","marks":2.0},{"part":"b","marks":2.0}],"Question-no":4,"total-marks":4.0}]}]
```

Definitely I am going to read this file again from a program, still this format doesn't looks good. I want this format:

```
[{
    "roll-no":1
    "Marks":[{
    "Question-no":1,
    "total-marks":6,
    "Parts":[{
        "Question-no":"a",
        "Marks":2
    },{
        "Question-no":"b",
        "Marks":2
    },{
        "Question-no":"c",
        "Marks":2
    }]
    },{
    "Question-no":2,
    "total-marks":5,
    "Parts":[]
    },{
    "Question-no":3,
    "total-marks":5,
    "Parts":[]
    }]
}]
```

I remember using a `pretty()` method in mongodb for achieving this, is there any similar method in java?

Would really appreciate any help!

Thank you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use this while initializing your object mapper

```
 mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Comment: I'm using json simple not jackson

Comment: @SatishTyagi Which json is it.. please tell me the package

Comment: json simple it is. I want the code that I have written to be intact, means the way I am writing json to file. Keeping it intact, I need something which can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `org.json.JSONObject` You can set the `indentFactor` i.e The number of spaces to add to each level of indentation,

```
reportCard.add(job.toString(4));
```

Note that, it is available in `org.json` not in `org.json.simple`

Comment: Can you please tell me in my code where to add this?