# parse Json data with array using java

Tags: java, arrays, json, api, gson

i use gson to get parese json data.but i have some problems
here is my json url data https://api.kcg.gov.tw/api/service/get/2c1d9959-d038-4918-bae3-409680f8193a

you can see that the json data have structure.

here is my code first

```
package iii_project;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class GsonFetchNetworkJson2 {
    public class ItemType {
        int seq;
        String 資料年度;
        String 統計項目;
        String 稅目別;
        String 資料單位;
        String 值;
//      public String toString() { 
//          return Arrays.toString(seq);
//      }
    }
    public class Item {
        String isImage;
        String success;
        String id;
        ItemType[] data;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [isImage=" + isImage + ", success=" + success + ", data=" + Arrays.toString(data) + "]";
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] ignored) throws Exception {
//    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
       URL url = new URL("https://api.kcg.gov.tw/api/service/get/2c1d9959-d038-4918-bae3-409680f8193a");
       InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
       Item dto = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Item.class);
       System.out.println(dto);
//       System.out.println(dto.isImage);
//       System.out.println(dto.id);
//       System.out.println(dto.success);

//       System.out.println(dto.types);
//       System.out.println(dto.data.toString());
//       System.out.println(dto.toString());
//       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.date));
//      Detail abd = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Detail.class);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abd.值));
//      System.out.println(abd.資料單位);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data));
    }
}
```

but the result of

```
System.out.println(dto);
```

i haved override it but still can not work
[image]

i want the data like this:
[image]

here is the answer!!!!

```
package iii_project;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class GsonFetchNetworkJson2 {
    public class ItemType {
        private int seq;
        private String 資料年度;
        private String 統計項目;
        private String 稅目別;
        private String 資料單位;
        private String 值;
        //getter and setter
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ItemType [seq=" + seq + ", 資料年度=" + 資料年度 + ", 統計項目=" + 統計項目 + ", 稅目別=" + 稅目別 + ", 資料單位=" + 資料單位
                    + ", 值=" + 值 + "]";
        }
        

    }
    public class Item {
        String isImage;
        String success;
        String id;
        ItemType[] data;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [isImage=" + isImage + ", success=" + success + ", id=" + id + ", data="
                    + Arrays.toString(data) + "]";
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] ignored) throws Exception {
//    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.getType();
       URL url = new URL("https://api.kcg.gov.tw/api/service/get/2c1d9959-d038-4918-bae3-409680f8193a");
       InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
       Item dto = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Item.class);
//     System.out.println(dto);
//       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data));
       System.out.println(dto.isImage);
       System.out.println(dto);
//       for(ItemType element : dto.data) {
//           System.out.println(element);
//       }
//       System.out.println(dto.data);
//       System.out.println(dto.id);
//       System.out.println(dto.success);

//       System.out.println(dto.types);
//       System.out.println(dto.data.toString());
//       System.out.println(dto.toString());
//       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.date));
//      Detail abd = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Detail.class);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abd.值));
//      System.out.println(abd.資料單位);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString` will internally call `toString` on each inner object. Therefore, your Details class needs to have that method **and** you need to use `Arrays.toString` rather than just print out the array itself

Answer (score 2):

Your dto.data is array, so your current output is the address of that array.
Replace your `System.out.println(dto.data)` by `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` to print your data array

Check out this to have more details: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: i used    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data)); but still can not work

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the toString function in your Detail class, otherwise it will only print out its address for the object.

Comment: Then use ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dto.data));``` to print

Comment: You can [edit] your response rather than comment to fix it

Answer (score 0):

> but still can not work

It works exactly as you've written it to!

> I want the data like this (*shows image of some JSON object*)

You need to *explicitly write the indentation* in your toString function, then

For example

```java
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\n");
    sb.append("  \"isImage\":" + isImage).append(",\n");
    sb.append("  \"data\":");
    if (data.length == 0) {
       // add empty array string "[]"
    } else {
        sb.append("[");
        for (ItemType it : data) {
           // create object string 
          // append to outer builder 
          // add a comma, but not for the very last object in the array 
        }
        sb.append("]");
    }
    // TODO: close off remaining end brackets 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And your ItemType class still needs it's own toString...

If you really just want to print indented JSON without much code, then don't try to print an Item class

[Pretty-Print JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)