# Displaying JSON list data in a new line

Tags: java, json, list, formatting, string-formatting

I have a JSON and in that it has a list.Inside the list I want to show each data in a new line(something like /n for Java Strings) but I get all the data inside the list in a single line .Is this possible to do ?Please see the following examples the "logWindow" prorperty.If so how to do it ?appreciate if someone can help

What I get

```
> > { "logs": [{   "exceptionTime" : "2022-01-07 13:36:01.0",   "logWindow" : ["1> 2022.01.07 13:35:32 > Opened ", "1> 2022.01.07
> 13:35:32 > Disposed gui>Used mem:>247233> Max mem:>477364","1>
> 2022.01.07 13:35:35 > Opened: .JournalFrame>Used mem:>151413> Max mem:>477364> 1 frames are open.","1> 2022.01.07 13:35:54 >
> Openeddialog: .components.CambioDialog>Used mem:>212689> Max
> mem:>477364",  
>                   ]   }   ]   }
```

Expected result

> 

```
{"logs": 
[
{
        "exceptionTime": "2022-01-07 13:36:01.0",
        "logWindow": ["1> 2022.01.07 13:35:32 > Opened ", 
                      "1> 2022.01.07 13:35:32 > Disposed gui>Used mem:>247233> Max mem:>477364", 
                      "1> 2022.01.07 13:35:35 > Opened: .JournalFrame>Used mem:>151413> Max mem:>477364> 1 frames are open.", 
                      "1> 2022.01.07 13:35:54 > Opened dialog: .components.CambioDialog>Used mem:>212689> Max mem:>477364", 
                     ]
    }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Do you read your JSON from a file or is it basically a map?

Comment: I read it from two log files then map logs according to timestamp and convert them to JSON (using Jackson)

Comment: maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java