# How to apply prettyPrint

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath, pretty-print

I have the following code that extracts some values from a JSON string, but I want to also apply the prettyPrint() method so that it is more readable. I applied it right in the end, but it obviously does not work. Is there any way to print my extracted response with the prettyPrint method?

```java
Response response = basicAuth.accept(ContentType.JSON).get(uri);
ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
JsonPath json= new JsonPath(body.asString());
String projects = json.getString("projects[1]");

System.out.println("I extracted this project "+projects.prettyPrint());
```

I also tried this according to the first comment but it's still no good

```java
Response response = basicAuth.accept(ContentType.JSON).get(uri);
ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
JsonPath json= new JsonPath(body.asString());
String projects = json.getString("projects[1]");
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(projects);

System.out.println("I extracted this project "+jsonOutput);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java

Comment: after you use "setPrettyPrinting" what is the output ?

Comment: I still get the whole json response in a single line.

Comment: Could you add more detail, like response json and screenshot of request, response log.

Comment: Given `java.lang.String` has no `prettyPrint()` method, how do you expect your first code sample to even compile? Similarly in your second example, what do you expect `gson.toJson` to do when it is offered a String?